# Lightning funding transaction unconfirmed by lncli after two weeks

Tags: mempool, lightning-network-daemon

After installing lnd on a Windows 10 machine and being able to do a first funding of 200ksats and a de-funding of 100ksats with on-chain confirmed transactions, I sent myself on-chain a larger amount two weeks ago.

While the first funding was reflected correctly in my wallet balance, the recent funding appears as unconfirmed balance after 10 days. On explorers the original transaction from my wallet has confirmed, but then a second transaction appears, I assumed initiated by lnd and this one has a fee of 5.00 sat/vByte and it stays pending for low fee.

How can I unblock it, and what is the syntax of funding transactions so that this does not happen to me again?